# If one void function returns, how do I stop the next function call from executing?

Tags: c#, return

I have two different button clicks that call modified versions of the same function...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ SendEmail(); }

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ SendRevisedEmail();}



public void SendEmail()
{
  DataManip(ref item1, ref item2);  //This is where I'd like the next 2 functions to not process if this one fails.
  UpdateDB(ref item1, ref item2);
  sendTechEmail(ref item1, ref item2);
}

public void SendRevisedEmail()
{
  DataManip(ref item1, ref item2);  //This is where I'd like the next 2 functions to not process if this one fails.
  UpdateDB2(ref item1, ref item2);
  sendRevisedTechEmail(ref item1, ref item2);
}
```

In the `DataManip` function, I have it performing some checks on the form and set to throw a pop-up Message and return; if it doesn't come out with a `flag1 = true`.

```
public void DataManip(ref string item1, ref string item2)
{
  bool flag1 = false;

  foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
  {
    Radiobutton rb = c as RadioButton;
    if rb != null && rb.Checked)
    {
      flag1 = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (flag1 == true)
  {
    //Manipulate Data here
  }
  else if (flag1 != true)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("You didn't check any of these boxes!");
    return;
  };
}
```

As of right now, the flag1 check in `DataManip` works fine.  I can verify that it doesn't process the data changes if it is missing an entry in groupBox1.

The problem is that within the `SendEmail()` and `SendRevisedEmail()` functions, it still processes the calls for the other functions after `DataManip(ref item1, ref item2)`.

How can I cause an error to kick out of `DataManip` and prevent/skip those other two function calls from executing?

Comment: Why are you passing everything by reference? It's unusual for that to be a good idea...

Comment: What is with the asterisks in the lines such as this: `**DataManip(ref item1, ref item2);**` ?

Comment: Because I've only been programming in c# for a week, and it seemed like a good idea...

Comment: Greg:  it was supposed to be BOLD formatting so I could show the function I'm working with

Comment: Keep the code valid. Remove the asterisks and add a comment after the important lines. ex: `DataManip(ref item1, ref item2); // Question here`

Comment: @JonSkeet What would be your suggestion in this case?  Again, I'm about 5 days into looking at this language, and haven't programmed anything since 2004...so to say I'm rusty would be a polite assessment...  Any reference material you would suggest I take a look at?  I'm not a programmer by profession, just trying to write up an app to help myself and my coworkers with a routine task.

Comment: @BigIrishApe: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html - it's important to understand how parameter passing works. (Your code doesn't use item1 or item2 at all at the moment as far as I can tell...)

Comment: No, it doesn't.  But the items it's passing are long, and I didn't want to spam the forum with all of the poo I've coded.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I cause an error to kick out of DataManip and prevent/skip those other two function calls from executing?

You have a few options:

- Change the method to return a `bool`.  This would allow you to return a value whether the method succeeds.
- If the method "failing" is a true error, raise an Exception.  This will allow the calling code to catch and handle the exception if required, or just bubble up if it doesn't know how to handle it.

Note that there are some other oddities in your code you may want to check.  It's rare that you should be passing everything with `ref`.  In addition, it's often not a good idea to use message box type notifications inside the same method that does manipulation of data - you may want to consider separating the validation/pulling of values from the manipulation of the data.

Comment: Will changing "public void DataManip(ref string item1, ref string item2)" to a "public bool DataManip(ref string item1, ref string item2)" affect the items it's returning?

Comment: @BigIrishApe You'll need to return true or false, but it won't change the values being changed via the arguments.

Comment: If I change it to "public bool DataManip(...)" will I need to add another parameter for the bool return, and then check that returned result before processing the other 2 function calls?

Comment: @BigIrishApe No - you just have to `return true` or `return false` where you return from the method.

Comment: @BigIrishApe `if (DataManip(ref item1, ref item2)) { UpdateDB(item1, ...`

Comment: Aside from my ugly code issues and passing by reference, it is now working exactly as I'd hoped.  Going to follow up with Jon Skeet's URL he suggested to learn more about passing parameters.  Thanks!!!

Comment: @BigIrishApe That's really a separate issue, but I would strongly recommend look at it - that's probably the strangest thing in your code right now ;)

Comment: Well, let me ask you this...essentially what I have is a form where my coworkers can input data, the DataManip function modifies certain parts of that data to a more "user friendly" format, then it creates emails based on options from the form, and also writes that data up to a Google Spreadsheet.

There is no real data being stored locally for me to protect by passing by value, I want the DataManip function to actually change the base data in the SendEmail function so that those data fields can be referenced by the other two functions.

Should I really not be passing those by reference?

Comment: @BigIrishApe I'd make a class to hold the values, personally.  That being said, you don't need to pass by reference into the SendEmail function, since it's not changing the values...